# C# Excercise Program doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

so I am new in programming with C#. This is a excercise I made which
should count until i press esc or it reaches 1 000 000 and should tell me how many loops("duerchlaeufe" in my programm)it made.But it doesn't work as I thought it would.Can you help me please?

```
       Int32 durchlaeufe = 0, i = 0;


        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            do
            {


                Console.Write("\n {0}", i = i + 10);
                durchlaeufe++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            }
            while (i <= 1000000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nDurchläufe:{0}", durchlaeufe);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_ exactly? It perfectly works on me and says `1000010 Durchläufe:100001` as a last part. Please be more specific about your problem. Read [ask] couple of times..

Comment: See the "… is not working" part http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check if a key pressed by user during the loop(by `Console.KeyAvailable`), and if so whether it is <kbd>ESC</kbd> or not, if so, break.

```
Int32 durchlaeufe = 0, i = 0;

do
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            break;
    }
    Console.Write("\n {0}", i = i + 10);
    durchlaeufe++;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}while (i <= 1000000);

Console.WriteLine("\nDurchläufe:{0}", durchlaeufe);
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this i what i wanted the program to do

Answer (score 2):

It does not exit when you press the escape key because it is not listening to the keypress inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to monitor for the key press inside the loop,  try something like this..

```
Int32 durchlaeufe = 0, i = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");
do {
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable && i < 1000000) {
        Console.Write("\n {0}", i = i + 10);
        durchlaeufe++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
   }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

Console.WriteLine("\nDurchläufe:{0}", durchlaeufe);
```